# Depositing cash to German Deutsche Bank account in Spain

Tags: germany, deposits, spain

I am going to stay in Spain and will receive some cash compensation during my stay. Since I already have Deutsche Bank and Norisbank account in Germany, I am hoping to deposit the cash to one of these accounts and withdraw while staying in Spain. Is it possible for me to go to any nearby Deutsche Bank Spain branch and use ATMs exactly as I could use in Germany, or would this incur some fees due to the fact that I am using German account in Spain?

Answer (score 1):

---

Withdrawing from German account:

- Look into the small print (services and fees document) of your accounts: these things are described there.
- Deutsche Bank says that you can withdraw without fees at Deutsche Bank ATMs in Spain.

---

Compensation:

- From Spain wiring money to your German account costs exactly the same as wiring money to a Spanish account (that's Euro/SEPA legislation).
  So maybe you could get the compensation deposited directly into your German account.
  (Though I have to say that some years back, I didn't get through with this argumentation in Italy - university there claimed they can deposit only to Italian accounts or pay me in cash. But that was when then SEPA legislation saying all wires within the SEPA zone must cost the same fees was brand new.)
- Deutsche Bank has branches in Spain. Ask them whether you can pay into your German account from their branches in Spain.
- If not, or if that turns out to be expensive, consider getting a cheap Spanish bank account where you can pay in the money and wire it to your primary account in Germany.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Deutsche bank fees and charges list](https://www.deutsche-bank.de/dam/deutschebank/de/shared/pdf/List-of-Prices-and-Services-Deutsche-Bank-Privat-und-Geschaeftskunden-01042016.pdf) PDF, it is free of charges if you withdraw cash from Spain Deutsche Bank branch.

This is stated on page 13:

```
Cash withdrawals by Deutsche Bank card holders : 
Debit cards and SparCard (savings account card)
using a Deutsche Bank Card, Deutsche Bank Card Gold1),
Deutsche Bank Card Service, Deutsche Bank Card Das Junge Konto or SparCard
.....
– at external payment service providers outside Germany
  - at Deutsche Bank Group branches abroad(9) and at branches of our cooperation partners abroad(10) 

9) Currently Spain and Italy
10) Bank of America (USA), Barclays (United Kingdom), BGL (Luxembourg), 
    BNP Paribas (France, including its overseas departments), 
    Scotiabank (Canada, Chile, Mexico),TEB (Turkey) and 
    Westpac (Australia, New Zealand).
```

If you use any other than the stated ATM services, e.g. other affiliate services not stated, you will be charged a minimum fee of 1% or EUR 5.99.

Answer (score 0):

Access is likely possible, but I would almost guarantee fees.

Depending on how often you'll be using your ATM card, you might consider opening an account in Spain for the duration of your visit.  Or open an account with a bank which has branches in Spain.  Have the deposits made to that account during your stay.

Comment: There are specific EU rules on fees between banks in member countries, could you add a reference to these since you mention fees, please?

Comment: E.g. Deutsche Bank has branches in Spain.